# Output user data fast on Cortex R5

Tags: c, debugging, arm, real-time, uart

I'm trying to output some user data, character series, on a Cortex R5 to a PC.
Problem is that the uart is too slow for the amount of data and I'm looking for something faster. I hoped ITM could be used but sadly that's only available for Cortex M-series. The data contains status info about processes which I'd like to visualise for a better insight.

The Uart was running at the maximum of 921600 baud thus I'm looking for something faster than that. I'm looking for 2-5 Mbit.

I found information of DCC (debug communication channel) and ETM but I can't really figure out their speeds and how I could use them with user data instead of tracing data.

I have acces to tracers and debuggers (Green Hills SuperTrace and Realview ICE) so requiring those is no problem. I just can't figure out how to read the data. Perhaps I missed the obvious?

Edit: For now it looks like the easiest way is to bypass the CP2105 which limits my uart to 921600. I'll connect the RX/TX pins from the SoC to a RPi which should be able to get much higher bauds. Ofcourse, I'll also need a logic level shifter since the SoC is only 2.5V tolerant (74LVC245). If this setup works I'll answer my question. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Clarify what you mean by *"too slow"* and *"amount of data"*.  RS-232 is going to be the simplest interface, so be sure it won't meet requirements before you abandon it.

Comment: Sadly the uart controller on the board doesn't allow anything faster than 921600 baud. I also need to share the uart with other debug data so I'm using a lot less than 921kbaud.

Answer (score 1):

The DCC is probably going to be slow, and maybe intrusive to use. You're limited to using JTAG to access this.

The ETM ought to be able to trace this information, and you should be able to configure the filtering to trace just the accesses to a specific memory address. Its a very  long time since I looked in detail at the ETMv3 data trace, so I'm not sure if you need to trace the associated instruction or not. The debug tools also tend to be more focused on tracing instructions with data being an additional decoration rather than presenting a raw datastream, so processing the data might be non-trivial.

The ETM should provide several bits of data throughput per cycle, so as long as the data is in small bursts there should be enough bandwidth. Obviously this is package dependant, but small numbers of Gbps are achievable (with a substantial protocol cost depending on what information you're trying to push through the trace stream).

In some chips, an ETM can be shared between several processors (of the same type). ETCSCR[14:14] will be non-zero if this is the case, and then you're limited to selecting one core and tracing that (until the ETM is disabled/re-programmed).

Comment: Trying to get the ETM tracing working, it only shows 3 of the 4 cores for some reason. Working on it, thanks for your input.

Comment: There may be one etm shared between cores. Numproc should this in an etm.